# History of differential and integral calculus

Tags: math-history

My math teacher told me that the research in differential calculus and integral calculus began on two separate tracks.Apparently people didn't know there was a relation between the two until some specific point of time.Now I don't want to know the date but I'm just curious about HOW the relation was discovered.

Comment: And on a side note, did you know that integration (as we would call it now) came earlier than differentiation? Archimedes was already way ahead of his contemporaries with his method of exhaustion. I think that last part of your question is a tough one. I honestly believe that must have been during the time of Newton and Leibniz, but the HOW part, well we can't look into their minds...

Comment: You can see [differentiation and integration](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705308/differentiation-and-integration).